# Prove that finite dimentional subspaces of normed vector spaces are topologically complemented.

Tags: functional-analysis

So I'm trying to solve the following exercise:

> If $X$ is a normed space and $Y$ a finite dimensional subspace. Show that $Y$ is complemented in $X.$

I know there's a proof of it using the Hahn-Banach Theorem, however I'm trying to prove it without that. 
My approach is to use the fact that there exists $Z$ such that $Y\bigoplus Z = X$, thus use the projection $P$ onto $Y$, there is a theorem that says that $ Y$ is topologically complemented if and only if $P$ is bounded. I thought it would be easy to prove that $P$ is bounded but I can't actually prove it.

Comment: The projection is bounded if and only if $Z$ is closed. But if $X$ is infinite-dimensional, then a nontrivial finite-dimensional subspace always has non-closed algebraic complements. So you cannot prove that the projection is bounded without further assumptions.

Comment: So the proof works completely fine if we can find some closed $Z$ that is a complement of $Y$ @DanielFischer

Comment: Well, yes. But finding a closed complement is more or less the task.

Answer (score 1):

It's fruitless to try to find a proof avoiding the HB theorem, because the statement implies at least this form of the HB theorem:

Theorem: Let $X$ be a NLS, $M$ a subspace and $\phi \in M^*$.  Then there exists $\psi \in X^*$ extending $\phi$.

Comment: OK, perhaps not fruitless, but you would be attempting to find your own proof of HB.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit on how the statement implies that version of HB that you state?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't thinking so clearly about this.  In any case, the special case of HB where you assume in addition that M is finite dimensional is equivalent to the statement in the original post.

Comment: I see. That special case is in fact evident.